# Add a Common field in all messages in google protobuf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, protocol-buffers

I want to add a common field to all the protobuf’s messages without having to mention it explicitly in every message’s schema, I don't know If there is already a way for that. Please help.

For example, I have this -

```
require 'google/protobuf'
Google::Protobuf::DescriptorPool.generated_pool.build do
  add_file("backend.proto", :syntax => :proto3) do
    add_message "proto.backend.ReconciliationRequest" do
      optional :state, :enum, 1, "proto.backend.ReconciliationRequest.ReconciliationState"
    end
    add_message "proto.backend.Action" do
    end
    add_message "proto.backend.Action.SendDocument" do
      repeated :documents, :message, 1, "proto.backend.Document"
    end
    add_message "proto.backend.Action.DisplayMessage" do
      optional :message, :string, 1
    end
    add_message "proto.backend.Action.AppRedirect" do
      optional :url, :string, 1
    end
  end
end
```

and I want to add -

```
optional :live_mode, :bool, 1
```

to every message without having to put this inside every message.

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure out how to do this?

Comment: No, I could not figure it out.